# Append param to iframe that loads in the DOM after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I'm trying to autoplay a YouTube video in an iframe. The iframe is loaded in the DOM when I click an trigger element: `a.colorbox.cboxElement`

How do I pass param `?autoplay=1` to the end of the iframe url on click when it doesn't exist yet?

Script that works on a loaded iframe:

```
jQuery( "a.colorbox.cboxElement" ).click(function() {
    jQuery("#colorbox iframe").attr('src', function() {
        return this.src + '?autoplay=1';
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use event delegation `on()`, so your `click` event will works also with the new iframes added dynamically :

```
jQuery( 'body' ).on('click', 'a.colorbox.cboxElement',function() {
   //Your logic
});
```

Hope this helps.